# C++ class member with constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

This is an extreme newbie question most likely but it's something I don't quite understand. It is probably something stupidly simple, but I don't have a lot of experience with c++ and am trying to learn.

I've tried to explain it with a much simplified version of what I am trying to understand.

I have a class called Foo. It's constructor takes two arguments.

I have a class called Bob in which I want a private instance of Foo, but, I won't know the arguments to pass to the foo constructor till I am inside the constructor of Bob.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int a, int b);
    ~Foo();

    int getA();
    int getB();
};

class Bob
{
public:
   Bob();
    ~Bob();

    void DoSomethingHere();
private:
    Foo foo;
};
```

When I compile the code I get an error.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()'
```

Based on that, I guess that it is trying to automatically call the constructor for foo, but doesn't know how.
In the code within the Bob class I was wanting then to do something like this. (bob.cpp)

```
Bob::Bob() {

    // do stuff to calculate the values of a and b

    int a = 12; int b = 23;

    // Initialize foo with the calculated values
}
```

Given that I won't know the arguments to pass to it until I am within the code in Bob, how do I handle that?

Comment: Keyword: `member initializer list`

Comment: `Foo` doesn't have default ctor. Make `foo` a pointer/smart pointer which will be initialized in the `Bob` ctor. Or provide default ctor for `Foo` and add methods like `void Foo::setA(...)`, `void Foo::setB(...)` which will be called in the `Bob` ctor.

Comment: `Bob::Bob(): Foo( calc_a(), calc_b() ) { }`

Answer (score 1):

There are various features in the latest revision of the C++ standard, C++11 and C++14, such as nested constructors, which can be used here. However, there are several alternative approaches, and you should give a more detailed example of what you're trying to accomplish.

I'll provide a simplistic answer that makes use of nested constructors. Suppose that the two parameters to `Foo`'s constructor must come from external functions, first_foo_parameter(), and second_foo_parameter():

```
extern int first_foo_parameter(), second_foo_parameter();
```

Then, the default constructor can work like this:

```
class Bob
{
public:
   Bob() : Bob(first_foo_parameter(), second_foo_parameter()) {}

    ~Bob();

    void DoSomethingHere();
private:

    Bob(int a, int b) : foo(a, b) {}

    Foo foo;
};
```

If the private class member's constructor parameters are to be derived in some more complicated way, there are other different techniques that can be used along the same lines. Sometimes the answer is to refactor the class hierarchy, such as a private superclass that gets initialized first, whose constructor has a free hand to make all the needed calculations, then by the time the subclass's members need to be constructed, all of their constructors' parameters are readily available in the fully-constructed superclass.

The answer really depends upon the specific details. The general approach is to use nested constructors, or private superclasses, to help in determining the parameters to all member constructors.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that for simple cases the use of a lambda instead of `first_foo_parameter()` and `second_foo_parameter` would be far more elegant and improve the readability of the code. e.g. replace `first_foo_parameter()` with `[](int d) { /* do something here*/; return d; }`

Comment: Excellent answer however +1

Answer (score 0):

I think a pointer maybe what you want.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    ~Foo() {}

    int getA();
    int getB();
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

int Foo::getA() {
    return a;
}

int Foo::getB() {
    return b;
}

class Bob
{
public:
    Bob();
    ~Bob();

    void DoSomethingHere();
private:
    Foo* foo;  // <--- Here is a pointer to foo.
};

Bob::Bob() {

    // do stuff to calculate the values of a and b

    int a = 12; int b = 23;

    // Initialize foo with the calculated values
    foo = new Foo(a, b);  // <-------- Here we create a new Foo object.
    std::cout << foo->getA();  // <--- Use `->` to reference method or field.
}

Bob::~Bob() {
    delete foo;  // <--- Deallocate the object.
}
```

In the client class, you can create new `Bob` object with default constructor.

```
int main()
{
    Bob bob;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some sort of pointer here and create `Foo` object right after computing your values. std::unique_ptr is suitable here.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int a, int b);
    ~Foo();

    int getA();
    int getB();
};

class Bob
{
public:
   Bob();
    ~Bob();

    void DoSomethingHere();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo; // <---- Here
};
```

And initialize like this:

```
Bob::Bob() {

    // do stuff to calculate the values of a and b

    int a = 12; int b = 23;

    // Initialize foo with the calculated values
    foo = std::make_unique<Foo>(a, b); // <---- And here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Place the following as a public function:

```
Foo::Foo()
```

You can have multiple constructors for a single class. This one is called if no parameters are given and which it looks like the compiler is looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the question.